# Class for exposing information with computer properties (getters)

Tags: swift

I need some advice on my code structure. I have read that setters and getters break one of the OOP principals, encapsulation, and that we should avoid them if possible but I cannot think of any other way to expose info other than getters.

I have a class which calculates price, savings and taxes based three inputs from the user through the initializer (initialPrice, discount and taxRate).

I'm using three computer properties to exposed the results, is this considered a bad thing? If yes, why and how can I improve my code?

Besides what I described above the class also has the ability to add all of the items in an array, assuming the instances of the CalculatorBrain were placed in an array.

Again, I'm more concern about the structure of my code. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
class CalculatorBrain {  

        private var taxRate:Double = 0  
        private var discount:Double = 0  
        private var initialPrice:Double = 0  

        func setInitialValues(initialPrice:Double, discount:Double, taxRate:Double){  
            self.taxRate = taxRate  
            self.discount = discount  
            self.initialPrice = initialPrice  
        }  

        private func salePrice()->Double{  
            return initialPrice - savings  
        }  

        var price:Double{  
            get{  
                return salePrice() + taxes  
            }  
        }  

        var savings:Double{  
            get{  
                return initialPrice * discount / 100  
            }  
        }  

        var taxes:Double{  
            get{  
                return salePrice() * taxRate / 100  
            }  
        }  

        internal func grandTotals(list:Array<Item>)->(grandPrice:Double, grandSavings:Double, grandTaxes:Double){  
            var grandPrice:Double = 0  
            var grandSavings:Double = 0  
            var grandTaxes:Double = 0  

            for i in 0..<list.count {  
                grandPrice = grandPrice + Double(list[i].totalPrice)  
                grandSavings =  grandSavings + Double(list[i].savings)  
                grandTaxes = grandTaxes + Double(list[i].taxes)  
            }  
            return (grandPrice, grandSavings, grandTaxes)  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your input, are you saying that my getters may not be so appropriate because they are exposing computed data? Sorry if I misunderstood it. Thanks

Comment: Titles on code review should describe what your code *does*, not what you want to achieve from the review.  Please edit your question to try and summarise the purpose of your code.

Comment: @forsvarir is correct, you might want to look at this help page http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell what your code does, it will attract more viewers and get you better answers. Ask your question in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Set Initial Values?

```
private var taxRate:Double = 0  
private var discount:Double = 0  
private var initialPrice:Double = 0  

func setInitialValues(initialPrice:Double, discount:Double, taxRate:Double){  
    self.taxRate = taxRate  
    self.discount = discount  
    self.initialPrice = initialPrice  
}
```

I don't care for this at all.

First, I don't see a good reason for these three properties to necessarily be `private`.  Why should the user have to guess what they've set their properties to?

Further more, you're not protecting these values from being reset.  The user simply has to call `setInitialValues` again.  The method name may be an attempted hint at that being the incorrect use of the class, but my mantra is let the compiler do as much for us as possible.

We should expose these properties to the user.  We should not allow the user to modify these properties after initialization.  We should write an `init` method.

```
let taxRate: Double
let discount: Double
let basePrice: Double

init(taxRate: Double = 0, discount: Double = 0, basePrice: Double = 0) {
    self.taxRate = taxRate
    self.discount = discount
    self.basePrice = basePrice
}
```

---

#### Why is `salePrice()` a function?

You have implemented basically everything else as a computed, read-only property.  Why can't `salePrice` also be a computed, read-only property?  If you want it to be private, that's fine if that makes sense for your class, but it can still be a computed property.

```
var salePrice: Double {
    return basePrice - savings
}
```

Also, note what I've done here.  The `get { }` is omitted.  Computed properties that just return a value can omit the `get` and are implicitly read-only.  Any code is assumed to be for the `get` if you have omitted the `get` & `set` keywords.

---

#### `internal` is the default access level.

You have marked some things as `private`.  You have omitted an access specifier on most things, and then your grand total method is specified as `internal`.  Marking `internal` is the same as omitting an access specifier.  You should drop this `internal` keyword here, or consistently use it with all the other properties.  None of your members are `public` in your current implementation.

---

#### About that `grandTotals` method...

This method *almost* seems out of place if it weren't for the fact that the class is called `CalculatorBrain`.  But it doesn't depend on any state, so it should probably be a `static` method.

Your [loop is far from optimal](https://github.com/metova/swift-style-guide#loops).  But, we don't even need a loop.  We can use `reduce`.

```
return list.reduce((0,0,0)) { 
    return (
        $0.totalPrice + $1.totalPrice,
        $0.savings + $1.savings,
        $0.taxes + $1.taxes
    )
}
```

But... I might avoid returning a tuple.  Why not just make a struct?

```
struct GrandTotal {
    let price: Double
    let savings: Double
    let taxes: Double
}
```

And now instead of a method that feels like it's in a weird place, we just add an appropriate `init`:

```
struct GrandTotal {
    let price: Double
    let savings: Double
    let taxes: Double

    init(list: [Item]) {
        let totals = list.reduce((0,0,0)) { 
            return (
                $0.totalPrice + $1.totalPrice,
                $0.savings + $1.savings,
                $0.taxes + $1.taxes
            )
        }
        
        price = totals.0
        savings = totals.1
        taxes = totals.2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very GOOD suggestions I will refactor to your suggestions. Quick question, on your first suggestion you suggest to make my variables inmutables (`let`) which makes a lot of sense but, so I know, can you please show me how could the user modify their values? I thought that by being `private`  was enough since they are not exposed. I just don't know  how could the user modify its values, sorry. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: All they have to do to modify them in your original implementation is call `setInitialValues` multiple times. Nothing in your code prevents that.

Comment: But if you want them to be immutable, use `let`. The compiler can sometimes make some optimizations over `let` variables which can't be made over `var` variables.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the clarification.  I really appreciate it.